# What is the proper arrangement for table-header-group?

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm trying to build a footer that has two title columns and three content columns.

I'd like to use `display: table-cell` for the content columns, and believe I need to use `display: table-header-group` for the title columns.

[image]

While researching `display: table-header-group`, I could not find any documentation *at all* on how to use this CSS property. W3Cschools says the following.

> table-header-group: Let the element behave like a `thead` element.
>   [(source)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

That unfortunately doesn't tell me how I should arrange my `divs`

So far I've got the following code, but I'm not sure if I'm using `table-header-group` correctly

```
.footer {
    display: table;
}

.footer-box {
    display: table-cell;
}

.footer-title-box {
    display: table-header-group;
}    

<div class="footer">
   <div class="footer-title-box">
      Title
   </div>
   <div class="footer-title-box">
      Title
   </div>
   <div class="footer-box">
      Content
   </div>
   <div class="footer-box">
      Content
   </div>
   <div class="footer-box">
      Content
   </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any experience with `table-header-group` and could shed some light on it, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C. The actual W3C spec is here, and it is far more detailed than W3Schools will ever be: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html

Comment: My apologies. I will edit that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any experience with it but logic dictates that you can only have **one** `thead` so you can only have one `table-header-group`

So your structure should, perhaps, look more like this:

[**JSfiddle Demo Backup Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrwyfyd/5/)

```css
.footer {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.footer-title-box {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer-row-box {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.footer-box {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-title-box">
    <div class="footer-box">Title</div>
    <div class="footer-box caption">Title</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer-row-box">
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer-row-box">
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer-row-box">
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to avoid having a separate `div` for each line?