# Set default header for each page by css?

Tags: html, css, printing

I working with my project for printing some documents.There I met some problem in set header for each print pages ! I want to print the html table that have so many `tr` ,its separated to two pages when print.Therefore,I want to set `thead` as header element for each print page.So help me !!

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 100%;
  color : green;
}
th,td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
@media print {
body * {visibility: hidden;}
#printable * {visibility: visible;}
#printable th {

    top: 0;
}
}
</style>
<div id="printable">
<span><center>Print Example</center></span>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>David</td>
            <td>3828</td>
            <td>83939</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Sheee</td>
            <td>3483939</td>
            <td>111111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>David</td>
            <td>3828</td>
            <td>83939</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>David</td>
            <td>3828</td>
            <td>83939</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>David</td>
            <td>3828</td>
            <td>83939</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>David</td>
            <td>3828</td>
            <td>83939</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr><tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr><tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr><tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr><tr><td>Jone</td>
            <td>39393</td>
            <td>0202022</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Smith</td>
            <td>39000383929</td>
            <td>0101010101</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here I also want `thead` to page 2 when print.(Running on Chrome)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Repeat table headers in print mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/css-repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)

Comment: Short answer is most browsers don't support repeating the `<thead>` on subsequent pages still. From the comments on the other question, Firefox and IE have implemented it.

Comment: @andyb Thanks for your comments ,I found that firefox is worked as you said.My testing browser is chrome,so dont worked!!! :)

Comment: For me in chrome `75.0.3770.142`, the OP code works fine? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCfuj.png

Comment: its working for me too, you should check  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode

Comment: You may have added additional styles to page 2. And also separate css from the html to css file for proper templating.

Answer (score 3):

Most browser do repeat  `<thead>` & `<tfoot>` including chrome latest browsers.

still there is way you can make the thead repeat like below.

```
<thead class="report-header">
   <tr>
      <th>
         <div class="header-info">
         ...
         </div>
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

And you need to provide css like:

```
@media print {
thead.report-header {
   display: table-header-group;
}
}
```

You can find detail description on below link.

[repeat header](http://www.jessicaschillinger.us/2017/blog/print-repeating-header-browser/)

Comment: @David Jaw Hpan if this helpful can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 table {
            -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        }
```

[https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/](http://flying-saucer)

This should work also

Answer (score 0):

You need some print-styling on thead:

```
@media print {
    /* Repeat header row at top of each printed page */
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This css code should do

```
@media print {
    /* Repeat header row at top of each printed page */
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194099/what-is-the-proper-arrangement-for-table-header-group) question. Slightly modified, added a second `footer-box caption` element, and solved with divs, not table elements.

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-title-box">
        <div class="footer-box">Title</div>
        <div class="footer-box caption">Title</div>
        <div class="footer-box caption">Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-row-box">
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-row-box">
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-row-box">
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer-box">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.footer {
    display: table;
    width:50%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.footer-title-box {
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.footer-row-box {
    display: table-row-group;
}
.footer-box {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```